# How to remove notification while remove app from taskmanager

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I couldn't remove notification while remove application from taskmanager.I tried this code but its not work for me

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mNotificationManager.cancel(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It may help you.

NotificationManager nManager = ((NotificationManager) contextgetSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
            nManager.cancelAll();